# in_array doesn't make any sense

Tags: php

```
$arr = array(
    'test' => array(
        'soap' => true,
    ),
);

$input = 'hey';
if (in_array($input, $arr['test'])) {
    echo $input . ' is apparently in the array?'; 
}
```

Result:
 hey is apparently in the array?

It doesn't make any sense to me, please explain why. And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `true == 'hey'` due to [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). What you're looking for is:

```
if (in_array($input, $arr['test'], true)) {
```

It forces an equality test based on `===` instead of `==`.

```
in_array('hey', array('soap' => true)); // true

in_array('hey', array('soap' => true), true); // false
```

To understand type juggling better you can play with this:

```
var_dump(true == 'hey'); // true (because 'hey' evaluates to true)

var_dump(true === 'hey'); // false (because strings and booleans are different type)
```

**Update**

If you want to know if an **array key** is set (rather than if a value is present), you should use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/isset) like this:

```
if (isset($arr['test'][$input])) {
    // array key $input is present in $arr['test']
    // i.e. $arr['test']['hey'] is present
}
```

**Update 2**

There's also [`array_key_exists()`](http://www.php.net/array_key_exists) that can test for array key presence; however, it should only be used if there's a possibility that the corresponding array value can be `null`.

```
if (array_key_exists($input, $arr['test'])) {
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. It's also looking on the values of each array key.

Comment: @John It's actually **only** looking at these.

Comment: @John I've updated the answer, in case you were looking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the array as a dictionary but the `in_array` function is to be used when you're using it like an array. Check [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: So you're saying I'm missusing array, please ellobarate if there are smarter ways to do, what im trying to achieve.

Comment: @John `in_array()` searches for a value. So it goes through each item and checks it against the needle. But if you're not using strict mode, `true == 'hey'` will evalute to TRUE. See my edit on Jack's answer.